# Progress Bar is not updated when File is Uploaded with ftp4j using AsyncTask

Tags: android, file-upload, ftp, android-asynctask, ftp4j

I have this code but the progress bar does not update the uploaded bytes/lenght of the file.

The progress dialog is displayed correctly but the progress stays in 0, then it simply disappears, the file was uploaded correctly but no progress is updated.

```
private class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        FTPClient client = null;
        String filePath = params[0];
        try {
            // Get the FTP Connection from the Utility class
            client = FTPUtility.connect(ipAddress, userName, password);
            //if directory is not there, create it.
            try {
                client.changeDirectory(params[1]);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                client.createDirectory(params[1]);
                client.changeDirectory(params[1]);
            }

            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    // Define the File with complete path to be uploaded
                    File fileUpload = new File(filePath);

                    fileSize= fileUpload.length();
                    Log.d("FTPSync", "File Size: "+fileSize);
                    Log.d("FTPSync", "Uploading the " + filePath
                            + " to Remote Machine");

                    // Upload the file
                    client.upload(fileUpload, new FTPDataTransferListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void started() {
                            // Transfer started
                            Log.d("FTP","TRANSFER-STATUS: File transfer started...");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(int length) {
                            int progress = (length*100)/((int)fileSize);
                            publishProgress(progress);
                            Log.d("FTP","Progress: "+progress);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void completed() {           
                            Log.d("FTP","TRANSFER-STATUS: File transfer completed...");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void aborted() {
                            // Transfer aborted
                            Log.d("FTP","TRANSFER-STATUS: File transfer aborted...");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void failed() {
                            // Transfer failed
                            Log.d("FTP","TRANSFER-STATUS: File transfer failed...");

                        }
                    });
                    Log.d("FTPSync", "Successfully Uploaded the "
                            + filePath + " File to Remote Machine");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    client.disconnect(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Operation Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage(message);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        pDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
private static class FTPUtility {
    public static FTPClient connect(String ipAddress, String userName,
            String password) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        Log.d("FTP","Connecting to " + ipAddress);
        try {
            client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
            client.connect(ipAddress);
            client.login(userName, password);
            return client;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The debug shows only one entry about Progress:100

How can I make the progress bar update.

NOTE: I've tried with small and large files, so it seems to be the same issue in both file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to sum length and put it in ProgressBar. Something like this:

```
public class MyTransferListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {

    JProgressBar jp;
    int transfBytes=0;

    public MyTransferListener(JProgressBar jp){
        this.jp=jp;
    }

public void started() {
    // Transfer started
        jp.setValue(0);
}

public void transferred(int length) {
    // Yet other length bytes has been transferred since the last time this
    // method was called
        transfBytes+=length;
        jp.setValue(transfBytes);
}

public void completed() {
    // Transfer completed
        jp.setValue(jp.getMaximum());

}

public void aborted() {
    // Transfer aborted
}

public void failed() {
    // Transfer failed
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
client.upload(fileUpload, new FTPDataTransferListener() {
                    int progress = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void started() {
                        // Transfer started
                        Log.d("FTP","TRANSFER-STATUS: File transfer 
started...");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void transferred(int length) {
                        progress = progress + length;
                        publishProgress((int) (((float)progress * 
(float)100) / (float)fileSize));
                        Log.d("FTP","Progress: "+progress);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void completed() {           
                        Log.d("FTP","TRANSFER-STATUS: File transfer 
completed...");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void aborted() {
                        // Transfer aborted
                        Log.d("FTP","TRANSFER-STATUS: File transfer 
aborted...");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void failed() {
                        // Transfer failed
                        Log.d("FTP","TRANSFER-STATUS: File transfer 
failed...");

                    }
                });
```

Comment: please explain your answer a little?

Comment: Sorry for late reply
In my case adding the length to the progress was not enough, but the calculation " (int) (((float)progress * (float)100) / (float)fileSize) " for calculating the progress percentage solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
    @Override
            public void transferred(int totalTranfered) {

                // Sets the progress indicator to a max value, the
                // current completion percentage, and "determinate"
                // state
                percent = percent + totalTranfered;

                int percentage = (int) ((percent * 100)/ fileSize);
                Log.e("Percentage Transfered", " " + percentage);
                mBuilder.setProgress(100, percentage, false);
                // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
                mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
                //                            publishProgress(percent);
            }
```